# Cambiar una propiedad heredada en CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

Tengo un div padre que tiene estas propiedades:

```
#DestineShowStyleContainer {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  height: all;
  width: all;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Y un componente hijo:

```
.DestineShowStyle {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  height: all;
  width: all;
  top: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  bottom: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

El componente hijo hereda todas esas propiedades, las cuales puedo cambiar a todas, a excepción del `opacity`. Por más que le dé el valor `1`, sigue quedando transparente.

¿Alguna idea?

> **Nota:** Estoy trabajando en React, no se si es relevante.

Comment: Alguna regla mas debe estar impidiendo logres lo que buscas, por que yo acabo de probar en un ejemplo tu código y funciona sin problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes hacer lo que quieres con css, ya que el contenedor padre genera la opacidad incluyendo todos los elementos que estén dentro de él.

En suu lugar si no tienes mas elementos hijos en el contenedor padre, te recomiendo dar opacidad el background con rgba...

```
#DestineShowStyleContainer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red; /* estás sobreescribiendo esta propiedad, por lo que no necesitas colocarla */
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* blanco al 50% de opacidad */
}
```

Por cierto, la propiedad `all` no es aplicable a `width` o `height`, en su lugar usa pixeles o porcentajes.

Comment: Anduvo perfecto, no conocía la opacidad con rgba. Muchas gracias!